# What will happen if there is not TEMP variable set or if it is set what will happen if the folder/drive does not exist?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, ramdisk

I want to setup a RAM disk for various purposes and among them I would want to set the TEMP variable to point to a folder in the RAM disk. I haven't done this yet, but the RAM disk will be initialized before logging on and I have a certain problem:

If for some reason the RAM disk fails to start, what will the result be? The TEMP variable will still point to `F:\Foo`, yet the `F:` drive will not exist.

Additionally, what will happen if I don't set a TEMP variable in the environment variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows actually sets 4 "temp" variables:

TEMP and TMP for the current user, plus TEMP and TMP for the system. (Scroll through the list of system variables to see them.) So if you don't set them, nothing bad will happen because Windows does it for you.

As for setting it to a nonexistent drive or folder, that depends on the application. Well-written applications check if an object or setting exists before trying to use it, and abort gracefully if it does not exist. Bad applications just display a sometimes-useless error, or they just crash.